# In PDFBox, Is it possible to add a tooltip (hint) to a mark annotation?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

**In a Nutshell**

I've been working on a program that gets a pdf, highlights some words (via pdfbox Mark Annotation obj) and saves the new pdf.

I'd like my highlighted words to show a tooltip with some small description on it, like a hint.

For instance, I want that on my pdf, the highlighted word *activated* shows the tooltip *important word found* when I stop the mouse over it.

[This](https://pdfhost.io/v/4wwNIO1Q_Oncogenic_BRAF_Induces_Melanoma_Cell_Invasion_by_Downregulating_the_cGMPSpecific_Phosphodiesterase_PDE5A.pdf) is the original test pdf.

**My Code**

With a couple of abstractions, in a nutshell, I have:

```
File file = new File("path/to/myfile/mypdf.pdf");

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
txtMark.setRectangle(pdRectangle);
txtMark.setQuadPoints(quadPoints);
txtMark.setColor(getColor());

annotations.add(txtMark);
```

**Current Result**

Currently it generates a pdf with mark annotations like below on the word *activated*:

[image]

**What I Want**

Now I want to add a tooltip on it, just like I have when I add a hyperlink, like showed below, but with a free text instead. I can only have a tooltip like this if this is attached to a url, even if I added the string I need, pdfbox would internally create a uri out of it...

[image]

FYI: this is the annotation link code:

```
PDAnnotationLink link = new PDAnnotationLink();
link.setAction("www.stackoverflow.com");
link.setRectangle(pdRectangle);
link.setQuadPoints(quads); annotations.add(link);
```

**What I've Tried and Why I'm Not Satisfied Yet**

1) I've tried to add an annotation link, as showed above, but with a description instead of a url, like *important word found*. The result isn't good, the tooltip is transformed to something like: *file:///Users/myproject/root/important word found*.

Also this link annotation is not the recommended way to go since in some cases I will want to have both a URL and a Tooltip. But if I could turn it around, it would be a real consideration.

2) I've tried to add a content to my mark annotation, which works like a popup, like showed below:

[image]

It works... when I mouse over it, my tooltip description shows up beautifully. However, you can see that bubble icon just above the word. That's the only problem with this solution, these bubbles are quite annoying and end up overlapping important part of the text and polluting the pdf. If I could hide them or something I'd be satisfied too.

[here](https://pdfhost.io/v/SwVulx2S_Oncogenic_BRAF_Induces_Melanoma_Cell_Invasion_by_Downregulating_the_cGMPSpecific_Phosphodiesterase_PDE5A.pdf) is the doc with this annotation.

And the code to add this popup was simple adding the line below:

```
txtMark.setContents("Important word found");
```

**Conclusion**

Any tip to either add a tooltip nicely or remove that annotation bubble will be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As @Tilman Hausherr suggested on comments, I've added the following line to my code:

```
txtMark.setTitlePopup("Important word found");
```

Without setting the content. I don't have the annoying bubble anymore, but now I need to double click my annotation and a not much good looking or practical popup shows up:

[image]

This helps a little bit since it's the best I got so far.

**EDIT 2**

My attempt with PDAnnotationPopup: added to my code the lines below, as suggested by @Tilman:

```
...
PDAnnotationPopup pdAnnotationPopup = new PDAnnotationPopup();
pdAnnotationPopup.setParent(txtMark);
pdAnnotationPopup.setContents("Important word found");

// Just to make sure
pdAnnotationPopup.setInvisible(false);
pdAnnotationPopup.setNoView(false);
pdAnnotationPopup.setNoZoom(false);
pdAnnotationPopup.setLocked(false);
pdAnnotationPopup.setHidden(false);

annotations.add(pdAnnotationPopup);
```

I also explored other PDAnnotationPopup parameters such as *setOpen*, *setRectangle*... and tried to keep it coexisting with *txtMark.setTitlePopup*.

Unfortunately none of that affected my code in any way. Only when I set *setOpen(true)* plus setRectangle I could see something: a completely empty popup over each of my text mark annotations.

Comment: Please try "setTitlePopup", would that help? If not, you'll gonna need PDAnnotationPopup (I don't have the time to help right now, sorry, hopefully the class name will give a hint). Btw you shared the link that you're not meant to share. You should have shared the "share link".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for your reply, links are correct now. "setTitlePopup" isn't the perfect solution yet, since it requires me to click on the annotation, then the popup shows up with the set title. This is not much pretty and practical, but definitely helps. So far this is the best I got. I tried to play a bit with PDAnnotationPopup without success, also couldn't find anything that would guide me a little bit on this. Anyway, many thanks.

Comment: try setParent() on the popup annotation. The parameter is the the main annotation. In the main annotation call setPopup(), the parameter is the popup. Also set some text with setContents().

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hi, I've updated the question with my attempt with PDAnnotationPopup, as you suggested. Unfortunately I couldn't see any results out of it. Thanks once again

Comment: Hmm, the next step would be to find a file that has the feature that you wish. One could then inspect the file with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hey, I've tried the setRolloverAppearance method, inspired by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144941/in-pdfbox-how-to-create-a-link-annotation-with-rollover-mouse-over-effect
It had potential to work, but unfortunately the appearance only takes the form of my current annotation, it can't expand or anything (we can manipulate the text, not the action itself). However it turns out that with your suggested setTitlePopup only, I can see the tooltip perfectly on pdf.js, so it will suffice for now... updating the question/answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up going with @Tilman suggestion, adding  a setTitlePopup to my mark without setting the content. In order to the annotations and their tooltips be visible through some viewers, like pdf.js, it's also needed to call the constructAppearances method:

```
txtMark.setTitlePopup("Important word found");
txtMark.constructAppearances(new PDHighlightAppearanceHandler(txtMark, pdDocument));
```

While this is not perfect, since it requires a double click on the annotation to be displayed and it's visible only by more robust pdf readers, like Adobe, it is the best solution I could find so far and will suffice. Also it meets my expectations perfectly if you wrap the pdf with [pdf.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46rbo.png), like showed below:

[image: pdf viewed with pdf.js]